# Скрипт аккордион

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Нужно сделать вот такой [аккордион](http://adamsmith.at.ua/) 
Подскажите, может есть готовое решение?

Comment: вам на js надо или css3 ?

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ - аккордион, только стили другие.

Comment: Это я знаю)) Только вот его не могу пока в обратную сторону развернуть...

Comment: В обратную - это как?

Comment: Раздвигаться вверх, как на примере, а не вниз.

Comment: В примерах - Fill space

Comment: он ведь итак раздвигается вверх, первую вкладку по умолчанию сделайте открытой

Comment: Да нет... Здесь такая структура (<h3>Вкладка-1</h3><div>Контент-1</div><h3>Вкладка-2</h3><div>Контент-2</div>), а надо такую (<div>Контент-1</div><h3>Вкладка-1</h3><div>Контент-2</div><h3>Вкладка-2</h3>)

Comment: @zhekonya, что мешает поменять структуру и стили? :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще [пример](http://pcvector.net/scripts/slideshow_and_scroller/140-vertikalnyy-razdvizhnoy-akkordeon.html) (5-й вариант), правда там такая же конструкция, как у UI аккордеона, но вдруг... поможет.